# Как написать nginx роутинг php вместо 404 ошибки?

Tags: nginx, config, php-fpm

Необходимо написать роутинг, чтобы когда был запрос по site/dir/123, в случае отсутствия файла 123, был переадресован запрос на site/dir/index.php?code=123
На Apache это было реализовано так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]*)$ index.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Сейчас сервер на PHP-FPM + NGINX, нашел конфиг который относится к тому домену, для которого нужно сделать роутинг. Пытался использовать несколько разных конструкций, вроде

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
  rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?code=$query_string;
}
```

или

```
error_page 404 = @routing;
location @routing {
  rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
}
```

Но ничего не получилось. В результате конфиг файл сейчас выглядит так

```
server {
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    charset UTF-8;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.com/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/bot;
    root $root_path;
    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
                        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?code=$query_string;
                }

        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
    }
    listen 1.1.1.1:80;
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@site.com";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/www-root.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    error_page 404 = @routing;
        location @routing {
                rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
        }

}
server {
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/site.com_le1.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/site.com_le1.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
    charset UTF-8;
    index index.php index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.com/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/bot;
    root $root_path;

    location / {
                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?$query_string;
                }
        }


    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
    }
    listen 1.1.1.1:443 ssl;
    location @php {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@site.com";
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/www-root.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    error_page 404 = @routing;
    location @routing {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last; 
    }
}
```

в результате все равно
**404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0**

в самом index.php прописано

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
var_dump($_GET);
```

Методом тыка логов

```
return 200 "test";
```

Нашел часть кода, которая как раз выполняется во время этой 404 ошибки. Это самые последние строчки

```
error_page 404 = @routing;
  location @routing {
  ....
}
```

Но чтобы я не писал на место ...., страница все равно возвращает 404 и никакой index.php файл не запускается

Comment: В своей точке входа в проект где вы стартуете приложение, если не находит страницу в проекте, то делайте редирект, вам здесь совсем не нужен nginx, по идее

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев Я не понял. Можете объяснить, что Вы имеете в виду под приожением, проектом и т.д.?
У меня есть centos, на нем стоит php, nginx и еще несколько нужных программ.
Загружены несколько php скриптов. Мне нужно, чтобы заходя на сайт site.com/get/123 запускался скрипт site.com/get/index.php?code=123 
Каким обрахом здесь можно обойтись без правил для nginx?
У меня нет апача, если что. В общем, я совсем не понял Вас. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы что нибудь слышали про единую точку входа? https://www.programulin.ru/chpu-routing-edinaya-tochka-vhoda-na-php#edinaya-tochka-vhoda-v-nginx я, правда, не в курсе особенностей вашего проекта, но, если это учебный проект, то вам, возможно, было бы проще реализовать чпу через пхп

Comment: Суть `location` в том, что если nginx находит максимальное совпадение, он за пределы этого `location` не выходит (если не указано обратное)! А у вас аж 2 `location /`! Это ошибка раз. Вторая ошибка, после `rewrite` нужно поставить `last`, иначе каким образом будет обрабатываться сам php?